# Accessing Through PHP a Posted Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I realize that there are several similar questions that have been asked, but none of those have been able to get me over the top. Maybe what I wnat to do is just not possible?

I have a page on which there is an order form. The admin can create an order for any user in the database by selecting them in the dropdown menu and then fill out the form. But each user may have a PriceLevel that will give them a discount. So I need to be able to make a database call based on the username selected in the dropdown and display their price level and be able to use the username and pricelevel variables in my PHP.

I have the an add_order.php page on which the form resides, and an ajax.php which makes a quick DB call and returns the results in a json format.

The problem I am running into is actually getting the information from jQuery into the PHP. I have tried using the isset method, but it always comes back as false.

Here's what I have:

add_order.php

```
<?php
// $username = $_POST['orderUser']['Username'];
$username = isset($_POST['orderUser']) ? $_POST['orderUser']['Username'] : 'not here';
echo 'hello, ' . $username; 
?>
```

...

```
$('#frm_Username').change(function() {
    orderUser = $(this).val();

    $.post('/admin/orders/ajax.php', {
            action: 'fetchUser', 
            orderUser: orderUser
        }
    ).success(function(data) {
        if(data == 'error') {
            alert('error');
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
})
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
$action = $_POST['action'];
if($action == "fetchUser"):
    $un = $_POST['orderUser'];

    /*if($un):
        echo $un;
        exit;
    endif;*/
    // SET THE REST UP WITH MYSQL
    if($un):
        $qid = $DB->query("SELECT u.Username, u.PriceLevel FROM users as u WHERE u.Username = '" . $un . "'");
        $row = $DB->fetchObject($qid);
        // $row = jason_decode($row);
        echo json_encode($row);
        exit;
    endif;
    echo "error";
endif;
?>
```

I am logging to the console right now and getting this:

```
{"Username":"dev2","PriceLevel":"Tier 2"}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should search by some user_id with an index, probably auto_incremented instead of username

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. You should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: check your request on the developers console, to see what values javascript is sending

Answer (score 0):

After calling `$.post('/admin/orders/ajax.php', ...)`, the PHP code which sees your POSTed variable is **ajax.php**.

You need to check in there (inside `ajax.php`), whereas currently your `isset` check is in `add_order.php`, which does not see the POST request you send.

You do seem to have some logic in `ajax.php`, but whatever you've got in `add_order.php` is not going to see the data in question.

Comment: And therein lies the problem. Is it even possible for me to do this?

Comment: @JasonLyman Even possible to do what? Have your JavaScript work, and have the PHP read the value? Yes of course, do it in `ajax.php`. If you mean something else, can you clarify?

Comment: I would like to know if I can send the JS variable from order-form.php to ajax.php (which I have been able to do) then bring it back to order-form.php and use it. It sounds like I can't do that. Maybe through an include on the order-form.php?

Comment: You _cannot_ send a JS variable like that (you can send a PHP variable, containing the data from JS, from one PHP file to another; but that's different, and the distinction matters here). What you've done is different - you've triggered a *new instance of PHP*, starting at ajax.php.